# AssertionError on assertThat on a list

Tags: java, assertion, hamcrest

I'm sending 2 rows of data from my cucumber feature file:

```
Scenario: Verify the data in the summary
    Then the 'Summary' section contains the following data:
     | Time Frame: 06/22/2016 20:47:22 UTC to 09/18/2016 17:00:53 UTC          |
     | Tabs: 47def , tr1 , e998                                                |
```

I'm trying to check that the data from each row of my feature file is found in the actual text that was pulled from the page:

```
public void sectionContainsTheFollowingData(String section, List<String> expected) {
    // text data pulled from the page is stored in 'actual'
    List<String> actual = SUMMARY.getSummaryData(section);
        for (String cell : expected) {
            assertThat(String.format("Did not find %s in data %s", cell, actual), actual.contains(cell));
        }
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Did not find Time Frame: 06/22/2016 20:47:22 UTC to 09/18/2016 17:00:53 UTC in data [Time Frame: 06/22/2016 20:47:22 UTC to 09/18/2016 17:00:53 UTC Tabs: 47def , tr1 , e998]
```

I'm not sure why I get this error. I can see that "Time Frame: 06/22/2016 20:47:22 UTC to 09/18/2016 17:00:53 UTC" is in both the actual and expected.
I'm guessing that my assertion is looking for an exact match, but I don't want an exact match. I just need the text from each row of the data table in the feature file to be somewhere within the actual text pulled from the page.

Answer (score 2):

With streams:

```
for (String cell : expected) {
    assertThat(String.format("Did not find %s in data %s", cell, actual), actual.stream().anyMatch(string -> string.contains(cell));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but if a few characters are missing off the beginning or end, the test still passes.